Barcode reader not working in landscape mode on iPad 6th generation running iOS 17.4.1
I'm encountering an issue with the barcode reader on my iPad 6th generation running iOS 17.4.1. Specifically, when I attempt to use the barcode reader in landscape mode, I do not receive any output or response. However, when I rotate my iPad to portrait mode, the barcode is successfully scanned.
I've tried restarting my iPad, checking for software updates, and adjusting the settings within the barcode scanning app, but the issue persists. I've also tested with different barcode scanning apps, and the problem remains consistent across apps.
This issue seems to be specific to my iPad model and iOS version, as I haven't encountered it on other devices or with previous iOS versions.
Has anyone else experienced a similar issue with barcode scanning in landscape mode on the iPad 6th generation running iOS 17.4.1? Are there any known solutions or workarounds for this problem?

Is this an external bar-code reader, and if so, what brand or model? What app are you using to read the bar-code?

This issue is only happening in iPad 6th generation with version 17.4 or higher.
